# Android Map not show in emulator

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to import [this project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3R4b-KauuI) and run it.After that it show the following photo without map,i don't know how to do it now.I m sorry I don't have reputation to upload image ,so please just click this link to view [my image](http://postimg.org/image/ferzehatp/).Help me out please.

Comment: generate the necessary key for that device.

Comment: how to generate it sir,give some guide sir,thank you @MarianoZorrilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must generate your SHA-1 fingerprint like this:

For Linux or OS X, open a terminal window and enter the following:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

For Windows Vista and Windows 7, run:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Once you have the fingerprin, go to [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/start), select a project, or create a new one and Enabled Map v2 API.

Last part would be add the generated key in your Manifest:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="API_KEY"/>
```

Where API_KEY (inside value) is your actual API KEY. Full documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup